# React-Native-Router-Flux disable text resizing in Header?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using React-Native-Router-Flux.  Is there a way to disable dynamic text in the header when the user allows large text in Settings? When the user allows dynamic text, I can disable dynamic text in the components inside the Scenes, but I can't in the header. I would expect `allowFontScaling={false}` to be able to be applied to the header text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be achievable by adding following property in your root scene:

```
headerTitleAllowFontScaling = {false}
```